# I would like to insert each list item into a div at particular intervals

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have a div and I would like that when then customer clicks on a button a list item from my list is inserted into the div at a particular interval.

I know I have to use setInterval or setTimeout but i am not sure how.
I have provided code below here is my js fiddle for more clarity https://jsfiddle.net/angie11/2d9cb8oq/

At the moment the list just displays in one block rather than line by line...

Tried to write a setinterval function and failed.

```
recipe = {
  coffee: ["Boil some water", "Brew the coffee grounds", "Pour coffee in the cup", "Add sugar and milk"],
  lemonTea: ["Boil some water", "Steep the water in the tea", "Pour tea in the cup", "Add lemon"],
  chocolate: ["Boil some water", "Add drinking chocolate powder to the water", "Pour chocolate in the cup"]
}

const lemonTea = document.getElementById("lemon");
const coffee = document.getElementById("coffee");
const chocolate = document.getElementById("chocolate");


lemonTea.addEventListener("click", () => { prepareDrink("lemonTea")});

coffee.addEventListener("click", () => { prepareDrink("coffee")});

chocolate.addEventListener("click", () => {prepareDrink("chocolate")});


function prepareDrink(drink) {
  const steps = document.getElementById('steps');
  const selected = recipe[drink];

  selected.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    steps.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${element}</li>` );

});


}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting to happen in a function that you are not showing. Please show us how you've written the `setInterval` code. Also, please consider using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create an example that can be run.

Comment: Maybe you want [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uota5c6e)

Answer (score 1):

You could add an index multiplier to the timeout.

```
selected.forEach((element, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    steps.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${element}</li>` );
  }, index * 500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much just what I needed!!